# ¿Es necesario tener un Mac para compilar una app para IOS con XAMARIN.FORMS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

mi consulta es la siguiente , si es necesario tener un ordenador MAC original para desarrollar con xamarin.forms tanto para android/ios y poder publicar en las tiendas. Tengo entendido que se puede desarrollar con visual studio para ios, ademas de la licencia de desarrollador IOS.

Comment: Si te fue de utilidad la respuesta, considera en marcarla como aceptada mediante click en el check verde. https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Revisa este enlace para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí, es obligatorio por efecto del ecosistema Apple.

Hay una alternativa económica:

https://checkout.macincloud.com/

Esta es la opción más barata y segura en el mercado.

Ve por el server dedicado.

Ahora, para la licencia de desarrollador, son 99$ USD al año. Esto para que puedas publicar tu app en la AppStore, de lo contrario, tendrías que utilizar TestFlight del mismo Apple para que instales temporalmente la app en tu iPhone, iPad, iPod.